# Can an AVL tree be build with complexity of O(n)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to build an AVL tree with a sorted array.Is it possible doing it with complexity of O(n)? And if yes i would love to see example code code. 
thank you!

Comment: Depends. Is it possible to 1) sort by key comparison in O(n) 2) construct a perfectly balanced binary tree (no node with one child only but for the last completely filled level) from pre-sorted data in O(n)? Can you assign AVL-style "balance factors" to the nodes of such a tree? `i would love to see example code code` What did you come up with yourself?

Answer (score 0):

AVL tree is nothing but self balancing binary search tree.  Hence refer the below code.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/

Comment: It is worth to describe an approach or show pseudo-code. At this moment your answer is "link-only" (though right). Don't forget to mention how to set balance factors